# keras - pixelwise classification of images

Tags: python, image, deep-learning, keras, loss

I have a dataset consisting of images which have certain objects of interest to be detected. It is a pixelwise classification problem, similar to image segmentation. I have annotated each image to create a corresponding mask. 
I have 2 classes for the objects in the images based on the size of the objects.
Therefore, my input would be a MxNx1 image, and the output would be a MxNx2 image. 
Each channel of the output image has 0 in background pixel locations, and 1 in the pixel locations that contain the object of interest. 
I am confused regarding the loss function to be chosen. I know, that a categorical cross entropy should do the trick, but I am unsure regarding how to modify it for an output tensor of size MxNx2, because, traditionally the loss function works on 1 dimensional tensors.

I have two questions:

1. An output tensor of size MxNx2 as described above, or an output tensor of size MxNx1 where background pixels represent 0, class 1 objects represent 1 and class 2 objects represent 2. Which of the above is suitable for ease in implementation of the loss function?
2. Loss function modification based on answer to question 1.

Comment: No need to modify the loss function. Keep the MxNx2. It already considers the last axis. You will have 2 classes.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot!